# Disable specific IE9 Addon in IE using c# and add-in Express

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9

I created one Application for IE9. when that application launch on IE9 at that time I want to disable specific Addon of IE9 using c# or using Add-in Express. how can I get control over that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The IE object model doesn't provide such a possibility. Moreover, when you disable an add-on in IE, you need to restart the browser. **Otherwise**, the add-on is still running.